# How to fix the error "The emulator process for AVD has terminated" on MacOs M1

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded android studio to my mac and encountered an error "The emulator process for AVD Galaxy_Nexus_API_30 has terminated". It seems to me that I have already tried everything that is on this topic on the Internet, but nothing helps. In the console I see this : WARN -  - Unable to determine if Galaxy_Nexus_API_30 is online, assuming it's not.
How to fix this?

I've tried absolutely everything

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.